# How can conservation of momentum coexist with conservation of energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

COM posits that Mass*Velocity is constant, and COE posits that 0.5*mass*velocity^2 is constant.

If i have a 10kg box moving left at 10m/s, it has Momentum of 100 and Kinetic energy of 500.
If i then place a 10kg box on it while it's moving (assume both are covered in velcro so they stick together), how fast will the two move now. If we assume that COM holds, then the boxes would both travel at 5m/s together, 5*20=100. However, this makes the kinetic energy be 250, because 0.5*20*5^2 = 250.

Comment: That's not the statement of conservation of energy, it's that the *total energy* is a constant in time.

Comment: Kinetic energy is not conserved property. You’re getting off on the wrong foot

Comment: Why not? Kinetic energy is energy, where have those 250 joules gone?

Comment: @IfFishThenSticker The kinetic energy is lost to heat, because the two velcro surfaces undergo a friction-like force, which is not conservative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Momentum is definitely conserved here, as given Newton's first and second laws it is logically equivalent to the third. However, conservation of energy is not strictly a law of Newtonian mechanics, but of thermodynamics. The boxes absorb the missing energy into internal degrees of freedom when they stick together. They might vibrate, or heat up. Adding in that excess energy will give you proper conservation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its really interesting, i assumed there would be some way to handwave non-kinetic energy by saying frictionless vacuum. Is it possible that whatever velcro substance I used in my hypothetical would somehow hold potential energy after the collision?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the above comments, it is total momentum and total energy that are conserved. Kinetic energy is not conserved separately.

The example you describe is an example of an inelastic collision where kinetic energy is not conserved. The kinetic energy lost goes towards non-mechanical forms of energy like heat when the two objects collide.